# Is it possible to add colors to Outlook's Categories color palette?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, colors

"Out of the box" it looks like there is a fixed palette of colors on Outlook when defining Categories. It seems odd that it when selecting a color it doesn't just allow you to selected any color.

Is there any way to selected different colors beyond the defined palette?  Can it be done programmatically via an add-in?

Comment: [How to add more color categories in Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1309-outlook-add-color-categories.html) doesn't work for you?

Comment: @DavidPostill I think the author is referring to the pre-configured set amount of colors in the color palette box that opens when selecting a new color for a category

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same question and was looking up and down for an answer.

In short: The answer seems to be "no", Microsoft does not provide such functionality.

It is partially explained in [this](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/get-color-categories-and-restore-them-using-vba/) article; creating more seems not to be possible, as the colours are coded fix and identified by the numbers `1 - 25`.

Answer (score 0):

I see this answer is 3 years old--it is possible today.  When you click on the color category (in edit category function), then select more colors, a color wheel comes up.

Comment: For me, Outlook does not show a "more colors" option. Could you maybe elaborate with some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as the color assigned is an enum, as [listed here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olcategorycolor).

In this way, no color wheel comes up. The colors are hard-coded.